# Calculating the checksum of the JAXB output stream before marshalling to xml to file

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, checksum, outputstream

We are having strange issue in our production environment. We have to generate thousand of xml files each of which around in 100MB in size.

We are using JAXB with XSD validation to generate the xml files. But sometimes(so far happened 2 times in 6 months) the generated XML file is jumbled/corrupted.

But we are not finding any errors/exceptions in our server logs.
So we are suspecting the issues is not when generating the XML file but while writing to the file system as we are using NFS(Network File System) to store all our files.

Since we are not able to find the root cause we are thinking of adding extra validation step like checking the content checksum before and after file write.

Now the question is,

1. Is there any way to get the checksum of XML before writing to file. Like calculating the checksum of the output stream?
2. is there any other means of validating the integrity of data written to the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [CheckedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/CheckedOutputStream.html) that you perhaps can use as `OutputStream` when marshalling the content? Then you could use [CheckedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/CheckedInputStream.html) to read the data back again and see if it has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this.
There is a class called "DigestOutputStream", that serve this purpose and it is available in JDK.